# Auto-imports/types not working with my NPM package

Tags: typescript, npm

I wrote an NPM package in TypeScript with two files, `index.ts` and `utils.ts`. Both of these files contain exports that I would like to be accessible to any clients that use the package. **All of the constants/functions that I want to be accessible I re-import and re-export from `index.ts`.** So for example my `utils.ts` might look like this:

```
export const add = (a: number, b: number) +> a + b;
```

Since I want clients of the package to be able to use `add`, with its types, I export it from `index.ts`:

```
import { add } from './utils';

export { add };
```

Then, I use `tsc` with the `declaration: true` flag to compile these files and their declarations to an `outDir` of `lib/`. So I end up with four files in `lib`:

```
- index.js
- index.d.ts
- utils.js
- utils.d.ts
```

In my package.json, I've set the `main` to `lib/index.js`, and `types` to `lib/index.d.ts`. Finally I linked this package so I could use it on another project in my system.

**Here's the issue.** I can get the imports to work with their types. For example, I can do something like:

```
import { add } from "my-lib"
```

And things mostly work fine. There's two problems:

1. There's no auto import. With other packages, when I start typing the names of functions/constants, an auto-import is suggested. I suspect that this is because the `index.d.ts` file does not specify types for the `add` const, so the IDE doesn't immediately recognize its existence.
2. Even after I import, the IDE's Intellisense seems to not know that the function has types. When I type `add(`, I don't get any intellisense or type recommendations like I usually do. It just says `import add` for the type. However, I know types are actually working, because if I provide bad types like strings, there is an error.

I figure that this is happening because my `index.d.ts` does not declare a type for `add()`. But I'm not sure how I can go about this -- there doesn't seem to be a way to get Typescript to combine all type declarations into the single `index.d.ts` file. Is there a way to automatically get all the types in `index.d.ts` so clients can get auto-imports and the like, as every other library seems to do? Obviously, I don't want to have to combine all my source code into a single `index.ts` file.

Comment: This seems to be simply a problem with your IDE, so it might be a good idea to tell us which IDE you're using. Also, the errors reported by your IDE might be different than reported by the TypeScript compiler when you run `tsc`, so trying that might help your investigation.

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad Using WebStorm. But I don't think its the IDE because I'm also importing functions from other libraries and I get Intellisense normally. I think it has something to do with the fact that the types aren't declared in index.d.ts